# How to read username and password from http GET in .NET MVC controller?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, jsonp

How can I read the username and password from http GET in .NET MVC controller? I am using a jQuery [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call and I am passing username and password in as a setting.

1. Is this secure?
2. If my server is ASP.NET MVC 2 how can I retrieve the username and password from the request?

My end goal is to make a secured jsonp call.

here is how I am making the call in javascript

```
    $("#getSomethingButton").click(function () {
        var username = "myusername";
        var password = "mypassword";
        $.ajax({
            url: 'people/getSomething',
            username: username,
            password: password,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonpCallback: 'onGetSomething'
        });
    });
```

here is how MVC receives the request

```
public string GetSomething(string callback)
{
    string data = "{data: 'test'}";
    return string.Format("{0}({1});", callback, data);
}
```

if I watch the request in fiddler this is how it looks

> http://myusername:mypassword@localhost:29161/people/getSomething?callback=onGetSomething

If and when this is put in production it will be SSL/HTTPS only but of course the query string is not secured by that.

So the question is can I in any possible way secure a password with a jsonp GET request?

Comment: jsonp, to my understanding, is better for cross-domain requests. Is that what you're doing?

Comment: Exactly I want to make an API call from another domain with javascript but the password must to be secured or the project will be canned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, be very careful while passing sensitive data using GET

Comment: That is the question. How can I secure the password?

Answer (score 4):

To send the username/password using AJAX:

```
// Obviously the username/password should not be hardcoded but read from an input
$.get('/home/foo', { username: 'foo', password: 'secret' }, function(result) {
    alert('username/password sent');    
});
```

To read them:

```
public ActionResult Foo(string username, string password)
{
    ..
}
```

> Is it secure?

Only if you are using HTTPS.

I would recommend you sending sensitive information like this only with POST verb ([`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)).

Comment: Thanks!, I agree a post would be better but my end goal is jsonp where post is not an option.

Comment: In this case make sure you are using SSL.

Comment: I tested this and it does not work. username and password are passed on the query sting even post will not secure that.

Comment: When using SSL, query string is **secure**. A man in the middle attack won't be successful as the whole communication is encrypted. The only gotcha is intermediary proxy servers that might log the request url. There's not much you can do about this with JSONP.